# How to pass element with dynamic reference angular2?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have elements inside `ngFor` loop. Each elements get reference like this `#f{{floor}}b`. As you see `floor` is a variable.
I want to pass these elements to a function.
Code:

```
<button #f{{floor}}b (click)="onClick(f{{floor}}b)"></button>
```

I tried this but it only pass a string like this `f5b` not the element itself:

```
<button #f{{floor}}b (click)="onClick('f'+floor+'b')"></button>
```

Full code:

```
<div *ngFor="let floor of floors">
  <button #f{{floor}}b (click)="onClick('f'+floor+'b')"></button>
</div>
```

`floor` is a number and `floors` is an array of numbers.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is okay to have same template variable name inside `*ngFor`, no need to make unique template variable name inside `*ngFor`.

**Html**

```
<div *ngFor="let floor of floors">
  <button #fb (click)="onClick(fb)"></button>
</div>
```

Even by having similar template name, you can query the DOM using `@ViewChildren` decorator.

```
@ViewChildren('fb') fbButtons:QueryList<any>;
```

Comment: Is this mean I cant pass `floor` or any dynamic var like this any `f{{floor}}b`?

Answer (score 3):

Just use the same variable

```
<div *ngFor="let floor of floors">
  <button #btn (click)="onClick(btn)"></button>
</div>
```

or use `$event.target/currentTarget`

Comment: Is this mean I cant pass `floor` or any dynamic var like this any `f{{floor}}b`?

Comment: You can't use interpolation to declare template reference variable

Comment: Angular way is use the same name because it has its own scope